# Why are perf back traces on Linux skipping a function (or showing a call to _init), with DWARF, LBR, and even FP (frame pointers)?

Tags: linux, callstack, perf, backtrace, stack-unwinding

I have a simple program that I compile with `-O0 -g -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-inline`, and which I record with system-wide recording

```
timeout 3 perf record -a -g -F 99 -- ./program
perf script > out.perf && ../FlameGraph/stackcollapse-perf.pl out.perf > out.folded
```

In `out.folded`, I see various incorrect stack traces, even when I add `--call-graph dwarf` or `--call-graph lbr` to the unwind strategy. I'm on Ubuntu with an Intel 9900K processor. Here's the program:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>

double a(double aa) {
  return sqrt(aa);
}

int main() {
  double aa = drand48();
  for (size_t i = 0; i < UINT64_MAX; i++) {
    if (a(aa) == 0) {
      std::cout << std::endl; // Side-effect
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Here are some example incorrect stack traces where they go straight from `main` to `sqrt` and skip over `a`, with various unwinding strategies:

**DWARF:**

```
a_39391_[003]__3819.799248:;__libc_start_call_main;main;__sqrt 91016627
a_39391_[003]__3819.817492:;__libc_start_call_main;main;a 71222327
a_39391_[003]__3819.831741:;__libc_start_call_main;main;__ieee754_sqrt 62644598
a_39391_[003]__3819.844274:;__libc_start_call_main;main;a 58633093
```

The first and third lines show `main` calling `__sqrt` without going through `a`

and these ones with **LBR** unwinding:

```
a_40294_[000]__4306.958241:;_start;__libc_start_main@@GLIBC_2.34;__libc_start_call_main;main;a;_init 69630243
a_40294_[000]__4306.972230:;_start;__libc_start_main@@GLIBC_2.34;__libc_start_call_main;main 63241775
a_40294_[000]__4306.984884:;_start;__libc_start_main@@GLIBC_2.34;__libc_start_call_main;main;a;_init 59031331
a_40294_[000]__4306.996696:;_start;__libc_start_main@@GLIBC_2.34;__libc_start_call_main;main;a 56209420
```

The second-last line shows a call from `main` to `a` to `_init` rather than `sqrt`.

**FP:**

```
a_40380_[001]__4360.292014:;__libc_start_call_main;a 84184457
a_40380_[001]__4360.308855:;__libc_start_call_main;a 70243465
a_40380_[001]__4360.322906:;__libc_start_call_main;main;__sqrt 63725332
```

The last line shows `__sqrt` without `a`

---

Here's a snippet from the compiled binary showing that `main` does indeed call `a` which in turn calls `sqrt`:

```
00000000000011c0 <_Z1ad>:
...
    11d2:   e8 59 fe ff ff          call   1030 <sqrt@plt>
...

00000000000011e0 <main>:
...
    1211:   e8 aa ff ff ff          call   11c0 <_Z1ad>
```

So neither were inlined or optimized to a `jmp` tailcall.

Does anyone have any ideas how to get better stack traces? Is it because perf is running async while the stack is being changed while it unwinds it, and if so, is there some tool on Linux that pauses the thread each time it samples it?

Comment: @Peter Cordes any ideas?

Comment: No, but I can reproduce it on my desktop (perf 6.5 on 6.5.9-arch2-1 x86-64 Arch Linux), even with simple `perf record` without `-a` system-wide recording.  I checked the asm, and despite `return sqrt()` being all one statement, `gcc` with the default `-O0` doesn't turn it into a tailcall.  And it doesn't inline it as a `sqrtsd` instruction the way it does with optimization enabled.  So despite that library function being extremely special and normally speculatively inlined (or non-speculative with `-fno-math-errno`), in this build the asm does make plain calls.

Answer (score 0):

This did *not* reproduce for me, using `perf` 6.5.13 on Ubuntu:

```
timeout 3  perf record -g ./a.out
[ perf record: Woken up 3 times to write data ]
[ perf record: Captured and wrote 0.745 MB perf.data (10362 samples) ]

perf script > f.out

cat f.out

a.out   57072 42799.672371:    1085145 cycles:P:
            7fc7fc30fd40 __sqrt_finite@GLIBC_2.15+0x0 (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6)
            563f3d7f21ae main+0x2e (/tmp/a.out)
            7fc7fbe456ca __libc_start_call_main+0x7a (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6)
```

That is the expected result for frame-pointer unwinder (since `sqrt` doesn't use frame pointer).

When I use `--call-graph dwarf`, I get the correct stack:

```
timeout 3  perf record -g --call-graph dwarf ./a.out &&
perf script > f.out

a.out   57391 43133.029241:     288559 cycles:P:
            7f23dfa8547a __sqrt+0xa (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6)
            56112adfd173 a(double)+0x1a (/tmp/a.out)
            56112adfd1ad main+0x2d (/tmp/a.out)
            7f23df6456c9 __libc_start_call_main+0x79 (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6)
            7f23df645784 __libc_start_main_impl+0x84 (inlined)
            56112adfd090 _start+0x20 (/tmp/a.out)
```

Same when using `--call-graph lbr`.

Comment: How'd you install perf?